# Need jQuery code to append parameters to all urls contained in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a jQuery code snippet which appends the parameter `action=xyz` to all urls within a page - note it should also check that if the urls already have other parameters appended or not: e.g., for a url such as `index.php?i=1` it should append `&action=xyz` and for urls without parameters like `index.php` it should append `?action=xyz`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$('a').each(function() {
  this.href += (/\?/.test(this.href) ? '&' : '?') + 'action=xyz';
});
```

That finds all the `<a>` tags and updates their "href" value as you described. You could turn it into a jQuery plugin if you need to pass different "xyz" values:

```
jQuery.fn.addAction = function(action) {
  return this.each(function() {
    if ($(this).is('a')) {
      this.href += (/\?/.test(this.href) ? '&' : '?') + 'action=' + escapeURLComponent(action);
    }
  };
}
```

Then you could just do `$('a').addAction("xyz");` or, in your case,

```
$('#yourDiv a').addAction("xyz");
```